# Single expansion of parameter in C macro

Tags: c, macros

I have a function `func` which expects a constant like `PREFIX_XXXX` as its argument. Also, there are macros like `#define a AAAA`. Is it possible to write a macro which, when called `macro(a)`, would expand to `func(PREFIX_AAAA)`? I tried `#define macro(x) func(PREFIX_##x)`, but of course this doesn't expand `a` to `AAAA`. Other ways I could think of didn't work either.

Comment: @Barmar: but when adding `#define macro_(x) func(PREFIX_##x)` and `#define macro(x) macro_(x)` I have `error: pasting "PREFIX_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token` at macro_.

Comment: Sounds like you have a space in the macro definition like *#define macro (x)* ... instead of *#define macro(x) ...*

Answer (score 2):

Arguments to the pasting `##` do not undergo macro expansion. Therefore you will need another interstitial macro, e.g:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a ## b
#define MACRO(x) func(CONCAT(PREFIX_,x))

MACRO(TEST)
```

To test, run `gcc -E` on the above, and you get:

```
# 1 "macro.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "macro.c"

func(PREFIX_TEST)
```

Is that what you were after?